# How do I port this from jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an Artificial Intelligence project. I have in a webpage a little tank and a grid, the tank is merely a div like this:

```
<div id="agent" ></div>
```

Then I use jQuery to do something like this:

```
agent = $('#agent').setUpAgent();

//examples of usage:
agent.goUp();
agent.goLeft();
agent.doActions['left','right','down']; // (will execute: goLeft, goRight, goDown functions.
```

The implementation of these methods is fairly simple:

```
Agent.prototype.goLeft = function() {
    this.agentDiv.rotate(45); // rotate the jQuery-wrapped div
    this.agentDiv.animate({"margin-left": "-=51px"}, "slow"); //51 is the step size
}
```

As you can see the movement on the agent is achieved by changing its margins through jQueryAnimate. Is it logical to port this to angularJS?. For instance like this:

```
<div agent="nameOfJavascriptObject" ></div>
```

since AngularJS will update my view automatically by setting up watches, how should I approach this? Should I have a model object with "actionsToBeExecuted" and when it's not empty I trigger the "goUp(), goLeft()..." etc functions? How can I make it so that functions are triggered when it changes? I am clueless as to how to port this, or even whether it should be ported at all.

Comment: You can probably wrap your agent animations in an Angular directive.  What is `nameOfJavascriptObject` for?  Whatever code you have that currently triggers an animation should now modify some model/scope property that the directive will $watch.  When a watch triggers, do the animation.

Comment: Yes but I don't exactly know how to do that

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple example, how you could do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7wG08Twvt7jufIpvjHFl?p=preview

You can simply express the appearance property of the agent (such as position, angle)
using javascript object and manipulate the properties.

In the directive, bind that object into scope and `$watch` the
apperance property and animate based
on how the properties changes.
(e.g. if `angle` changes then call `rotate()`)